# System.StackOverflowException C#

Tags: c#, recursion, model-view-controller, stack-overflow

How can I bypass a stackoverflow exception or is there a better way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public MetricItemDetail GetData(int itemId, int itemTwoId)
{

        //some of my code goes here..

         try
                {
                    return new Class
                    {
                        Value = GetItemDetails(itemId, itemIdTwo)

                    };
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
                    return new Class();
                }

}

public double GetItemDetails(int itemId, int itemTwoId)
{

   var currentValue = GetData(itemId, itemTwoId); // The problem is here..this is where I get the stackoverflow exception

}
```

Comment: I mean, you're stuck in an infinite loop...

Comment: `GetItemDetails` calls `GetData`, which calls `GetItemDetails`. See the problem yet?

Comment: `is there a better way to do this?` If by "this" you mean causing a stackoverflow then nope, you've already nailed it!

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking if there is way to bypass the stackoverflow exception. I know what the issue is @JeroenMostert

Comment: There is absolutely no information in your question. What are you trying to achieve? Where is the logic?

Comment: You can't "bypass" it. The way to *avoid* it is to not have two functions that call each other in an infinite mutual recursion. You must have an execution flow in at least one of the two functions where it does not call the other function, and there must be conditions where that flow is used, rather than an unconditional call. Think about what the functions are supposed to *do*, and it should become clear quickly why they're not currently doing it the way they're written. With only the code you've given here, the functions, together, do nothing.

Comment: @Bizhan What I meant was if there was another alternative / way to not have it cause an stackoverflow exception? Obviously, I don't want this. Do you have a way?

Comment: That's impossible, you are asking for a paradox, can't you see?

Comment: There is no logic. so even if you somehow "bypass" it, then what is it suppose to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetItemDetails and GetData methods are mutually called, it causes the "infinite" loop with stack allocations for each call, unfortunatelly stack size isn't infinite ;)

See more details here: https://www.dotnetperls.com/stackoverflowexception

StackOverflowException can't be bypased, it can't be catched, it must be avoided. It exists to protect .NET runtime from fatal crash.

Comment: `unfortunatelly stack size isn't infinite` that's not my impression of this question. More like: "at some point you have to tell the program what to do"

Comment: @coffeetime no need to get offended, I'm pointing out that this answer is stating "limited stack size" as in "if you increase it to infinte the problem is solved" is not the correct impression of this question. stackoverflow is usually caused when "there is NO LOGIC in the code" and the program isn't told what to do, and the program keeps ping ponging around without any purpose.

Comment: I understand now that that given code should demonstrate the stackowerflow principle, not the working code. You can try to enlarge stack memory and use an old version of .NET runtime (e.g. 1.1) which had been much more insensitive to asynchronous exceptions like StackOverflowException or OutOfMemoryException, and allowed to catch and bypass them on your own risk.